# How do I fix a Nikon F75 which refuses to load film with an "Err” message?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, film, repair, slr

I loaded a new film into Nicon F75, closed the door and turned it on.
However it seems like I did a poor job inserting the film because it did not clutch and I saw **“Err”** message on the screen.

I removed the film altogether and inserted another one instead.
The message stayed there, and the camera doesn't even attempt to load the new film now.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe it's just thinking really hard...
(sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happened to me from time to time with my N80.  Each time I simply opened the back and checked that the film canister was inserted straight and the film leader was pulled out the right amount.  Second time was always the charm.  A few times I had the leader out too far (passed the little red dot) and had to take the film canister out roll the leader in a bit and try again.

I hope that works for you.

Comment: Rolling the leader in just a bit did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Just had this same problem again—glad I posted it on StackExchange a year ago.